# find minimum length of triangle

Tags: geometry, circles

suppose that we have  $ABC$  triangle,with $AB=28$ and $C=120$,we should find minimum length of triangle,if it is know that  $AC:BC=3:5$,it is clear that  minimum side is $AC$,also because  sides are  in proportion $3:5$,angles is also proportion of  $3:5$,so i  will have following equation

$3*x+5*x+120=180$

$8*x=60$

$x=60/8=15/2$

i can find  angles  corresponding to   sides,but using sine theorem,how can i take exact  values  of for example $sin(15/2)$  or $sin(75/2)$?please help me

Comment: Use cosine rule. you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we must emphasize that there is no such proportionality between sides and angles in a triangle. The angles are not proportional to their opposite sides. The sine rule express a proportionality between **sides** and the **sines** of opposite angles.

Now if you follow the suggestion of Norman in his comment, you will have to solve the following equation:
$$28^2=(3x)^2+(5x)^2-2(3x)(5x)\cos(120^{\circ})$$
where $AC=3x$, $BC=5x$ and $AB=28$.